# Фильтровать список ForeignKey в Django

Tags: python, django

Суть проблемы следующая. есть модель:

```
class TerminalList(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, to_field='id', verbose_name="Пользователь GWM")
    terminal_id = models.ForeignKey(Terminals, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=lambda: Terminals.objects.get(status=0), null=True, blank=True, to_field='id', verbose_name="Терминал")
    start_work = models.DateTimeField('Start work', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    end_work = models.DateTimeField('End work', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

В модели Terminals есть поле status. Нужно чтобы при добавлении записи, в выпадающем списке отображались строки только с определённым значением в поле status, 1.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Форма Django используется?
Можешь так попробовать.
Переопределяем форму при инициализации и меняем поле на нужный queryset

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['terminal_id'].queryset = Terminals.objects.filter(status=1)
```